# How to use FloodFill for a Png graphics loaded in a TImage?

Tags: delphi

I want to use FloodFill function from TCanvas. 
I have an Image that its picture is a Png.
when I call

```
Image1.Canvas.FloodFill(20,20,clRed,fsBorder);
```

an error raised and said that "Can only modify an image if it contains a bitmap"

I wrote a piece of code like this to solve my problem.

```
procedure myChangeColor(p:TPngImage;colorSrc,ColorDest:TColor);
var i:Integer;
  j: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to p.Width - 1 do
    for j := 0 to p.Height - 1 do
      if(p.Canvas.Pixels[i,j]=ColorSrc)then
        p.Canvas.Pixels[i,j]:=ColorDest;
end;
```

It works fine! but the problem is that it takes to much time to perform this action :(

My png Image is 1.3 MB (High resolution. 14288x7200 pixel => 102 million pixel) and it takes around 2 min to change the color. It must be a way. because photoshop with it's paint bucket did around 2 sec.

How can I use floodfill for a png image in Delphi?

Comment: [`Scanline`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Imaging.pngimage.TPngImage.Scanline) would be a better alternative than `Pixels`.

Comment: @LU RD : Thanks very much! If U posted a piece of code I should marked it as the answer. but U didn't, I could get what I want from that scanline. to be honest scanline is better than FloodFill in my case. because I am working on a map component that should changing the color of countries every minute in a monitoring process. we have many contries that their border are complicated and if I wanted to use FloodFill that would be a hard work to save some points for each country png file to use for FloodFill function. this scanline is perfect for my work :D

Comment: Ok, but since using `ScanLine` does not answer the question how to use `FloodFill` for a PNG image, I just gave a good alternative. If you have any problems implementing the ScanLine part, this could be a new question. Happy coding :-)

Comment: As soon as you convert it to bitmap, you can use all functionality available for bitmaps, including direct scanlines access.

Comment: @TLama : Polygon? I really think that it is not a good idea. because a country on a map has a lot of vertices!

Comment: @Loghman, do what you want :-) If you feel you'll better fill a country area with `Scanline`, use it. Or, if you think you'll precisely fill it will `FloodFill`, do it. I just wanted to say, that if I were going to fill a country area, I would get a frontier description from the underlying GIS database and draw (the exact) polygon by using `Polygon` function (or similar from a vector graphics library), because my tiles are rendered from the same GIS database. Anyway, how did you wanted to fill that area with `Scanline` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert PNG to bitmap first, then you will be able to use canvas for such drawing:

```
procedure TForm15.Image1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  b: TBitmap;
  c: TCanvas;
begin

  // convert PNG->BITMAP
  b := TBitmap.Create;
  b.Assign(Image1.Picture.Graphic);
  Image1.Picture.bitmap := b;
  FreeAndNil(b);

  // draw
  c := image1.Canvas;
  c.Brush.Color := clBlue;
  c.Brush.Style := bsDiagCross;
  c.FloodFill(100,100,clBlack, fsBorder);
end;
```

UPDATE: If you need to keep it in PNG:

```
procedure TForm15.Image1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  b: TBitmap;
  c: TCanvas;
  png: TPngImage;
begin
  b := TBitmap.Create;
  b.Assign(Image1.Picture.Graphic);

  c := b.Canvas;
  c.Brush.Color := clBlue;
  c.Brush.Style := bsDiagCross;
  c.FloodFill(100,100,clBlack, fsBorder);

  Image1.Picture.Graphic.Assign(b);
  b.Free;
end;
```

UPDATE2 Same without converting:

```
procedure TForm15.Image1Click(Sender: TObject);
var png: TPngImage;
begin
  png := (Image1.Picture.Graphic as TPngImage);
  png.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
  png.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsDiagCross;
  png.Canvas.FloodFill(100,100,clBlack, fsBorder);
  Image1.Refresh;
end;
```

Comment: I tested your code. it works for bmp. but! when I want to convert bmp to png again it doesn't work! why? I don't know. btw it must become png again because transparency is needed. the scanline that LU RU suggested is worked better in my case. thanks.

Comment: @Loghman Question was quite specific, if you need something else, you should change/update the question or create new task.

Comment: :Thanks. the last code works fine. and U are right. the answer of the question that I asked is what U answered. :)